# Установка pip3 в консоле Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При попытке установить pip3 для питона `sudo apt -y install python3-pip`, консоль Ubuntu требует ввести какой-то пароль, хотя в примере https://losst.pro/ustanovka-pip-v-ubuntu, этого нет.
Я ввожу пароль от своего сервера, который так же вводил при входе в Putty, но мне выдает `sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt`

Что за пароль от меня требует? Можно ли установить pip3 без всяких приколов Ubuntu?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это пароль от root пользователя ubuntu, он может отличаться как от текущего пользователя, так и от Putty, уточните, к какому серверу вы подключаетесь

Comment: не от рут, а от cp20738

Comment: @eri зависит от настроек — https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Sudo#Root_password.

Comment: Это убунту и человек который пароль ввести не может врятли что менял

Comment: @ClickName, а где этот пароль найти? К какому виду сервера, это типо VPS/VDS и тд?

Comment: @ClickName Если это допустим не VPS/VDS сервер, а обычный хостинг для веб сайтов, он не годится разве?

Comment: Судо не дают на шаред хостинге. Проси поддержку или покупай vps